# Adding a WordPress Blog to a current WordPress site

Tags: blog

I currently have a WordPress website, though it's just a normal page with no need for constant updates or posts on it. What is the easiest way to add a WordPress blog to my website?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use an auto installer, for more info visit [Automated Installation Using Softaculous](http://developingsites.blogspot.com/2013/10/automated-installation-using-softaculous.html).

Comment: Are you saying to install WordPress into another directory?

Comment: I'm not sure what your situation is, but try to use an auto-installer first to find how.

Comment: I already have WordPress installed. Is it bad to have more than one wordpress installed in the same directory (or domain)?

Comment: What do you mean? You already have WordPress installed, lets say in *example.com* , do you also want to have another WordPress in *example.com/blog* ? You can check [WP Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) for that.. Or you just want to [give your WordPress its own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)?

Comment: if your WordPress site is showing just a page, you might have set that under 'settings - reading - front page shows...'; add another page and set that as the 'posts page' under the same settings. the above is assuming that you haven't vastly modified your theme.

Comment: Actually its not becoming clear what you are trying to do from  the query you posted. So please provide more details. But if you are searching for a theme then look for that here (https://wordpress.org/themes)

Comment: I already have wordpress installed in example.com, though I want to have a blog as well. I'm not sure whether I should install wordpress in a directory such as example.com/blog. I'll give the front page setting a try in reading.

Answer (score 0):

You use the front page setting in settings > reading. Select static for front page. Refer to this documentation: `https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page`